# Pass parameters in transition to default-response

Tags: moqui

It is strange when defining parameters in default-response

The parameters defined within default-response are not passed to the target url as below:

```
<transition name="editProductFeature">
    <path-parameter name="productFeatureId"/>
    <default-response url="../Feature">
        <parameter name="productFeatureId" from="productFeatureId"/>
        <parameter name="action" value="edit"/>
    </default-response>
</transition>
```

It does not work either when defining them in parameter-map:

```
<transition name="editProductFeature">
    <path-parameter name="productFeatureId"/>
    <default-response url="../Feature" parameter-map="['productFeatureId':productFeatureId, 'action':'edit']">
    </default-response>
</transition>
```

but it does work if adding an empty actions in the transition:

```
<transition name="editProductFeature">
    <path-parameter name="productFeatureId"/>
    <actions></actions>
    <default-response url="../Feature" parameter-map="['productFeatureId':productFeatureId, 'action':'edit']">
    </default-response>
</transition>
```

Comment: This looks like more of a bug than a question and would be best filed as a GitHub issue. I'll start looking into it.

Comment: I was not sure whether I did it wrong. I have filed one issue on github https://github.com/jonesde/moqui/issues/18